# Default select first bar of viz column graph when page loads in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I have used viz chart library. I have given some drill down functionality on the column graph. For that I have to select any column of the graph to see the detail for the selected part (in the same page).

Now I want to select my first column/bar of the column graph automatically. It means when I go to the graph page, the first bar should be selected as default and the detail of the selected bar should be there.

Please help me guys.

Code:

View:

```
<viz:ui5.Column id="chart" selectData="goToDaily" width="auto">
                <viz:plotArea>
                <viz:ui5.types.VerticalBar colorPalette="#FFCC00"/>
            </viz:plotArea> 
                <viz:title>
                    <viz:ui5.types.Title text="Monthly">  
                    </viz:ui5.types.Title>  
                </viz:title>
                <viz:dataset>
                    <viz:ui5.data.FlattenedDataset id="fds1" >
                        <viz:dimensions>
                             <viz:ui5.data.DimensionDefinition id="dim"  axis="1"  name="Month" value="{name}">
                             </viz:ui5.data.DimensionDefinition>   
                        </viz:dimensions>
                        <viz:measures>
                            <viz:ui5.data.MeasureDefinition id="mea" name="Values" value="{value}"> 
                            </viz:ui5.data.MeasureDefinition >   
                        </viz:measures>
                    </viz:ui5.data.FlattenedDataset>
                </viz:dataset>
            </viz:ui5.Column>
```

Controller:

Oninit:

```
JSONmodel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    data1 = [ {
        name : "Jan",           
        value : 100,
        },
        {
        name : "Feb",           
        value : 150,
        },
        {
        name : "March",
        value :120,
        }, 
        {
        name : "April",
        value : 200,
        }
        ];
    JSONmodel.setData(data1);
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("idPage3--chart").setModel(JSONmodel);
```

Select Data for Chart:

```
goToDaily:function(evt){
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("idPage3--chart").selection({ctx:[{dii_a1:1}]});   
}
```

I have tried to select month Feb as default selection, but not able to select it.

Regards,
Niket Talati

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Have you looked at the API?  There is a `fireSelectData` method, and the corresponding `selectData` event shows the object structure it expects to receive

Comment: I have tried many events but not able to do. I have also tried fireSelectData method, but not able to select first one. Can you please give me code for the same? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have tried, along with any console errors you received? This will make it easier to pinpoint what's wrong.

Comment: I have put the code here. Please suggest the changes. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things incorrect in your code

1. You have specified an event handler for `selectData` but this is obviously only triggered when you first "select data". You never fire an event for data selection in your code, so the event handler will only be triggered if you click on a column manually
2. It seems you tried to fire the event from the event handler (which is the other way around, see previous point), but you have never implemented the `fireSelectData` method.
3. In addition, the signature of the map you tried to select is incorrect. [According to the API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.viz.ui5.Column.html#event:selectData) (which is ill-formatted, I know) you need to send a whole lot more, something like this:

```js
    // ...snip...
    var oSelection = {
        data : [
            {
                target : oRect,
                data   : [
                    {
                        ctx : {
                            path : {
                                dii_a1 : 0,
                                dii_a2 : 0,
                                mg     : 0,
                                mi     : 0
                            },
                            type : "Measure"
                        },
                        val : 100
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        name : "selectData"
    };
    oYourChart.fireSelectData(oSelection);
    // ...snip...
```

4. If you need to get an element by it's Id when using XMLViews, you should use `this.getView().byId("chart")` instead

Hope the above helps!

Comment: Thanks for the Help Qualiture!! What is oRect? I am getting error like this oRect is not defined?

Comment: The `target` property expects, according to the API, "an object pointed to corresponding dom element" so in your case `oRect` should be a reference to the DOM element of the first column. I'm not sure, but I expect it to be an SVG `rect` element

Comment: I have passed rect also, then also same error. I have done inspect element, but not able to see this DOM element. Thanks for the help man!